# Swift TabularData DataFrame.append "Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1ba67cc48)"

Tags: swift, xcode, csv

i just want to insert value in a DataFrame created from a CSV File. 
i have my CSV file with just the header:
 ticker;shares;price;date 
i create the dataFrame with: 
`guard let myCsvUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "transaction", withExtension: "csv")  else { return } let options = CSVReadingOptions(hasHeaderRow: true, delimiter: ";") var dataFrame = try! DataFrame(contentsOfCSVFile: myCsvUrl, options: options)`

then i'd like to append rows and save the dataFrame to the CSV file...

this is the whole code i wrote till now:

```
import UIKit
```

import TabularData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var tickerUpdate: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var sharesUpdate: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var priceUpdate: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var dateUpdate: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
@IBAction func tickerText(_ sender: UITextField) {
    tickerUpdate.text = sender.text
}

@IBAction func sharesText(_ sender: UITextField) {
    sharesUpdate.text = sender.text
}

@IBAction func priceText(_ sender: UITextField) {
    priceUpdate.text = sender.text
}

@IBAction func dateText(_ sender: UITextField) {
    dateUpdate.text = sender.text
}

@IBAction func processButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let ticker = String(tickerUpdate.text!)
    let shares = String(sharesUpdate.text!)
    let price = String(priceUpdate.text!)
    let date = String(dateUpdate.text!)


    createCSV(ticker: ticker, shares: shares, price: price, date: date)
    
}
func createCSV(ticker: String, shares: String, price: String, date:String) {
    guard let myCsvUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "transaction", withExtension: "csv")  else { return }
    let options = CSVReadingOptions(hasHeaderRow: true, delimiter: ";")
    var dataFrame = try! DataFrame(contentsOfCSVFile: myCsvUrl, options: options) // Mark 1
    
    dataFrame.append(valuesByColumn: ["ticker": ticker, "shares": shares, "price": price,"date": date])

    try! dataFrame.writeCSV(to: myCsvUrl)
    print(dataFrame)
    
}
```

}

as soon as i press the UIButton, the app crashes with "Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1ba67cc48)"

Comment: Is there any error message in console? Which one? Because there are plenty reason that could make it crash. All the `!` are a reason to crash. Which line causes the issue?

Comment: Hi @Larme, ty for the quick response. the crash happen at dataFrame.append(valuesByColumn: ["ticker": ticker, "shares": shares, "price": price,"date": date]) and the console does't print any specific error (only (11db))